# Compound distribution representation

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, compound-distributions

Given a distribution function, under what conditions is it possible to represent it as a mixture over Bernoulli random variables?

For example, suppose you have a continuous random variable on an interval $[x_L,x_H]$. Pick any point in the interval, $x$, and find the conditional means $m_L(x)=E[X|X<x]$ and $m_H(x)=E[X|X>x]$. This contracts $X$ into a Bernoulli supported on $m_L(x)$ and $m_H(x)$, and this contraction has the same mean as $X$. That is, $\Pr(m_L(x))=F(x)$ and $\Pr(m_H(x))=1-F(x)$.  By varying the truncation $x$ throughout the support, one can construct a family of Bernoulli R.V.s.

Is there some way to mix over this family of Bernoulli random variables to generate $X$?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question initially.  The example indicates you want a mixture *of* Bernoulli variables, not "over" them.  The mixing distribution would generally not be Bernoulli. However, your example is not a mixture of Bernoulli variables because each of those variables is an *affine transformation* of Bernoullis.  I would therefore like to suggest that you edit this post to clarify what you are looking for.